# Positive Topographic Openness - do any FOSS tools (other than SAGA) provide this?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga, topography

I'm looking for a FOSS GIS tool to provide **Positive Topographic Openness** on 32-bit Ubuntu. (which rules out ArcGIS)

Normally [I use SAGA GIS for this](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_lighting_5.html), but my Ubuntu setup is a bit messed-up after a recent update, and SAGA is crashing on opening (I think it's down to a clash in GDAL versions, but that's a question for another day!)

Are there any other FOSS tools out there which provide this algorithm? I've looked in GRASS and [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) but can't find this algorithm.

I understand [Relief Visualization Toolbox](http://iaps.zrc-sazu.si/en/rvt) offers this, but the Linux version only supports 64 bit, and I'm still on 32 bit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GRASS GIS 7, there is [r.skyview](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.skyview.html) addon for sky-view factor, which is very similar to openness. You can check the implementation details [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass7/raster/r.skyview/r.skyview.py#L168). Download the addon with `g.extension r.skyview`.

Comment: that works, thank you! I'm using it for relief mapping, and aesthetically it looks very similar. Funnily enough, the same upgrade which broke SAGA gave me access to GRASS 7 :)